# 'children' is missing in props validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

so I am using this awesome react-context and hooks on an react proj structure in order to pass values from state into component but when I'm destructuring the children is warning me that `children' is missing in props validationeslint(react/prop-types)`.
The thing is I not really want to import PropTypes only for that eslint warning so what shoud be the best way to do it whithout PropTypes.

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from "react";

export const FormContext = createContext();

const FormContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    firstName: "",
    LastName: ""
  });

  const updateState = () => {
    setState({
      ...state,
      firstName: "Method",
      LastName: "Man"
    });
  };
  return (
    <FormContext.Provider value={{ ...state, updateState }}>
      {children}
    </FormContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default FormContextProvider;
```

Comment: /* eslint-disable react/prop-types */

You can disable the eslint rule for this file if children is the only property it uses. If the component gets extended at some point, you should probably take notice that eslint wont validate that.

Answer (score -1):

You can try below without `PropTypes` import

```
const FormContextProvider = (props) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    firstName: "",
    LastName: ""
  });

  const updateState = () => {
    setState({
      ...state,
      firstName: "Method",
      LastName: "Man"
    });
  };
  return (
    <FormContext.Provider value={{ ...state, updateState }}>
      {props['children']}
    </FormContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Comment: this is like putting a plaster on a broken leg. Would not recommend this approach